# Получение данных с ссылки

Tags: javascript, http, ссылки, ссылка

возник такой вопрос:

```
У меня есть ссылка *здесь что-то есть*?uid=BS6KyXdFv9hPLDaPZopKPx6UjjUDhQmagX1neyOns5LHmEUWadF9BAsZX2pQgALPrqDZ5PWW9cbr7lQV
```

Как мне в JS получить данные uid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно получить параметры GET-запроса

```
 let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams; 
 console.log(params.get("uid"));
```